# How can link two table with css pseudo-selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I am trying to make two different table able to listen each other with CSS pseudo-selectors, I have a created a data table and a auto-numbered table which is different table from data table. I am trying to achieve when user hover over td of data table whole row gets highlighted along with corresponding auto-numbered row, same when user hover over td of auto-numbered row, tr of data table get highlighted along with it.

I tried few approaches like using useState but I am aiming for pure CSS solutions. If anyone have some good insights do share them.

Also if this cant be achieved with pure css, can we use event handler with pseudo selector that would be also helpful. Please share your thoughts on it too.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lakshya-lalotra/pen/qBQbPmq)

```
.sticky-table tbody tr:hover td,
.auto-number-table tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: That's not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: What if we attach event handler with pseudo selectors? @yunzen

Comment: Yes you can look into attaching event handlers, but then you are immediately using Javascript and you explicitly state you are looking for a pure CSS solution. Could you update the question to say what the situation actually is.

Comment: Looking at your example if you just want a gap betwen the autonumbered row and the table then why don't you just use one table and remove all stying from the 2nd column? I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You could using the `:has()` pseudo class but it would be a lot of CSS and isn't supported in firefox. Marked up example below. The last css rule picks up where any element with a specific data-table attribute is hovered over, it highlights any table row with the same attribute value.

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding-inline: 0.25rem;
}

:has([data-row='1']:hover) [data-row='1'],
:has([data-row='2']:hover) [data-row='2'],
:has([data-row='3']:hover) [data-row='3'] {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
Data table
<table>
  <tr data-row='1'>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row='2'>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row='3'>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Autonumber table
<table>
  <tr data-row='1'>
    <td>Auto Row</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row='2'>
    <td>Auto Row</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row='3'>
    <td>Auto Row</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edited**
I've noticed on your example that your autonumber table sits next to your data table. Why not just have them both as one table then use css to remove the styling from the 2nd column to make it look like they're two separate tables? Then you don't need JS or complex css to control the row hover effect. Example below:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.sticky-table {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sticky-table td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sticky-table th:not(:nth-child(2)),
.sticky-table td:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.sticky-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sticky-table th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10px;
}

.sticky-table th:not(:nth-child(2)) {
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.sticky-table tbody tr:hover td:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sticky-table td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="sticky-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sorry @Adam , I seem to have read over that part. Apologies .

Comment: No worries. I thought I'd not mentined it and was going mad there for a minute! Old age makes me forgetful.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for this Adam, but for my use case both table has to be separate, that's why I am trying to find good approach to achieve with minimal re-rendering and reliable solution

Comment: If I was going it myself for production I'd use javascript imho